# Do I have to use an anonymous function with jquery's ajax complete option?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why can't I pass a named function to the jquery ajax complete option. Here's my code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: baseURL + '/' + controller + '/' + action,
        data: params,
        success: function(data){
          //do something
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            checkResponseCode(jqXHR, textStatus);
        }

    });
```

I wanted to just write out: "complete: checkResponseCode(jqXHR, textStatus);"

Comment: Adding parenthesis `()` after a function *calls* the function.

Comment: lol yeah just realized this!  thx for the correction guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function name, but this code is you invoking a function:

```
complete: checkResponseCode(jqXHR, textStatus);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `complete: checkResponseCode`

Answer (score 4):

You can shorten up the code, BUT, the line `complete: checkResponseCode(jqXHR, textStatus);` actually invokes the method `checkResponseCode`, which is clearly not what you want.

You can simplify it to just:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: baseURL + '/' + controller + '/' + action,
    data: params,
    success: function(data){
      //do something
    },
    complete: checkResponseCode
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little rusty, but wouldn't this work?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: baseURL + '/' + controller + '/' + action,
    data: params,
    success: function(data){
      //do something
    },
    complete: checkResponseCode
    }

});
```