# Is there a way to set a default function for the ajax completion event?

Tags: jquery

I want to have all ajax requests check the HTTP response code, is it possible to create a function and have this run for all my ajax requests by default?  Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply defaults for any of the [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) options by calling [`jQuery.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/). Based on your other questions you probably want something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        // Do your checking and logging.
    }
});
```

[Or even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379920/do-i-have-to-use-an-anonymous-function-with-jquerys-ajax-complete-option):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    complete: checkResponseCode
});
```

But keep in mind that this is called *after* your success or error callbacks.

Comment: Thx for the headsup mu.  This is really what I should have implemented.  Also, I was just looking through the documentation and noticed that there is a "statusCode" option, do you think I should just set that option, since all i'm really doing is checking the status code to make sure that the user's session hasn't timed/logged out?

Comment: @blacktie24: If you have a specific (and complete) "code to action" list then `statusCode` might be the right thing. If you're just logging all of them then `statusCode` might be a little verbose and the `complete` callback would be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Bind an event to `.ajaxComplete()`. I've done it before and I think I just did something like

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    //dostuff
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(e, xhr, settings){
        //global send
    }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(e, xhr, settings){
       //global complete
    }).bind("ajaxError", function(e, xhr, settings, thrownError){
      //global error
    });
```

Comment: more on Global Ajax Event Handlers: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/